# Making a simple C# API call

Tags: c#

I'm trying to teach myself how to make simple API calls with C#. I'd like to call this "http://hivemc.com/json/userprofile/da10b68dea6a42d58ea8fea66a57b886". This should return some strings in json but I don't know what i'm supposed to do with that.

reference: https://apidoc.hivemc.com/#!/GameData/get_game_game_data_id_UUID

I'm new to programming and I've never done anything with API's. I've tried looking around the internet but I don't understand what I'm supposed to look for. Can someone refer me to an article that can teach me how to do this? I have no idea where to start. An example of the code with explanation would be great but I understand if it's too much to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Use System.Net.HttpClient and look at the Newtonsoft.JSON nuget package.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Everything about Json is there.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can start from the following.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    public static void Do()
    {
        var result = GetGameData("da10b68dea6a42d58ea8fea66a57b886").Result;

        //TODO parse json here. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetGameData(string id)
    {
        var url = "http://hivemc.com/json/userprofile/" + id;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string strResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return strResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample call

```
Test.Do();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.Net.HttpClient` from Nuget. Check this [link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient) out. It shows you how to get data from the API. The next step is to deserialize it to your model using [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Hope it helps!